# ios CATransform3DMakeScale scaleup animation

Tags: ios, xcode, animation, subview, scaletransform

I have the following animation:

```
CATransform3D scaleTransform = CATransform3DMakeScale(0.1,0.1, 1.0);
scaleAnimation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:scaleTransform];
keyframeAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn];;
```

where I'm scaling down a subview. But I'm trying to do opposite. start from .01% of the size of the subview and go to 100% of the size of the subview. Does anyone knows how can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do this:

```
yourSubView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.01, 0.01);
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{ 
//change time duration according to requirement
// animate it to the identity transform (100% scale)
yourSubView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
} completion:^(BOOL finished){
// if you want to do something once the animation finishes, put it here
}];
```

Comment: how can add some movement to the animation like CGPathMoveToPoint using the above code?